# SwiftUI where to store and manage app specific files

Tags: swiftui

Where do I store files, like 1k png files, specific to my app in SwiftUI? I do not want them accesable from outside the app and I want to be able to download and delete them. I don't think CoreData is the right place for them or user defaults because they are not key value pairs.

I also need to know how much storage is available to the app for these files and manage this.

Comment: Storage has little to nothing to do with SwiftUI [FileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager) is one option but there are many others including 3rd parties, just research storage excluding the UI framework.

Comment: @loremipsum, if you are showing products and want to store or cache images on the phone, doesn't it have to do with Swift and storage? I saw CoreData has BLOB storage. There must be some limitation on storage for an app, right?

Comment: In CoreData you can store unlimited data, only limited by device free storage space

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "I want to be able to download and delete them"

Comment: Swift is a language SwiftUI is a framework, Storage has little to do with SwiftUI. Storage is limited by the device.

Comment: @ChrisR, download from a API, store on the device, delete from the device.

Comment: Do it with CoreData. There are many tutorials how to set it up. Create an Entity with an Attribute "id" of type "UUID" and an Attribute e.g. "image" of type "Binary Data". Then you can use e.g. `let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: xx)` to convert your images to data and store them in CoreData.